# Javascript update a dictionary according to list index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a list which contains a team according to color:

```
var team = ["Red","Green","Blue","Yellow","Black","White","Orange"]
var from = 0
var to = 5
team.splice(to, 0, team.splice(from, 1)[0])
console.log(team)
```

Here I am chaning the index of the team from 0 to 5 which gives me output like:

`["Green","Blue","Yellow","Black","White","Red","Orange"]`

The 0 index positioned to 5.

Now I have an dictionary which contains the captain for the team according to index.

`var captians = [{'index': 0, 'captain': 'Jack'}, {'index': 1, 'captain': 'Daniel'}]`

Here `0` is the index of `team`.
Team `red`'s captain is `Jack`
When team is changed in index I want to change the captains accordingly.

How can I do this ??

Comment: There are a few bad practices here. Firstly, don't assign captains based on index. Give them team id's. And convert the team array into an array of objects like `[{'id':0,'name':'Red'},{'id':1,'name':'Green'}.....]`

Comment: Btw, I saw what you did there (Jack..Daniel) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over and move all indices in the interval a position.

```js
var team = ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Yellow", "Black", "White", "Orange"],
    from = 0,
    to = 5,
    captians = [{ 'index': 0, 'captain': 'Jack' }, { 'index': 1, 'captain': 'Daniel' }];

team.splice(to, 0, team.splice(from, 1)[0]);

captians.forEach(function (a) {
    if (a.index === from) {
        a.index = to;
        return;
    }
    if (from < to && a.index > from && a.index <= to) {
        a.index--;
    }
    if (from > to && a.index >= to && a.index < from) {
        a.index++;
    }
});

console.log(captians);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
captians.map((item)=>
{
   if(item['index'] == to){
        item['index'] = from
   }else if(item['index'] == from){
        item['index'] = to
   }else{
        if(item['index']> from && item['index']<to){
               item['index'] -=1;
        }
   }
})
```

Comment: Your code works for placing 0 to 5.. but my teamlist is somehow different. When I map 0 to 5 the index 1 now moves to 0 and so on.. but it your case it remains as it is just it maps 0 to 5 and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

You need objects rather than array here. Following alterations work best in this situation:

```js
var team = {0:'Red',1:'Green',2:'Blue',3:'Yellow',4:'Black',5:'White',6:'Orange'};

var captains = {0 : 'Jack', 1: 'Daniel', 2: 'Mark',3:'Joan',4:'Sarah',5:'Mindy',6:'Stuart',7:'Jane'};

function swapTeam(from, to){
temp = team [to];
team[to] = team[from];
team[from] = temp;

temp = captains[to];
captains[to] = captains[from];
captains[from] = temp;
}





swapTeam(0,5);
console.log(team);
console.log(captains);
```